# Cleaning tweets using gsub in R

Tags: r

I am trying to clean a bunch of tweets using gsub.

```
V3
1  Well: Getting Insurance to Pay for Midwives http://xxxxxxxxx
2  Lightning may be giving you a headache http://xxxxxxxx
3  New York City is requiring flu shots for kids under 5 in city preschools and day care. Do your kids get the flu shot? http://xxxxxxxx
4  VIDEO: Can we erase memories entirely? http://xxxxxxxx
5  Artificial sweeteners are a $1.5-billion-a-year market @kchangnyt reported last year. http://xxxxxxxx
```

I tried to use the following code to remove all the links (taken from a previous question at SO):

```
newdf1$V3 <- gsub("http\\w+", "", newdf1$V3)
```

However, there was no change in the tweets.

Further, when I use the code `newdf1$V3 <- gsub("http.*", "",  newdf1$V3)`, I am able to remove the links:

```
V3
1  Well: Getting Insurance to Pay for Midwives 
2  Lightning may be giving you a headache 
3  New York City is requiring flu shots for kids under 5 in city preschools and day care. Do your kids get the flu shot? 
4  VIDEO: Can we erase memories entirely? 
5  Artificial sweeteners are a $1.5-billion-a-year market @kchangnyt reported last year.
```

Can someone explain why the code in the first case does not yield the desired results?

Answer (score 0):

That's because `\w` only picks up on alphanumeric characters. since http is always followed by "://", the `\w` doesn't recognize it as a legal expression.

In contrast, `.*` just picks up anything that follows the "http", so that works.